# Locking people out of public computer with one-time use code

Tags: parental-control, windows-xp

At our office we have a computer (Windows XP) that anyone can use for one hour. We have the built-in parental controls enabled, so it automatically logs off after one hour. However, once the user is logged off they can just log back in and use the computer for another hour.

I'm having trouble finding software that will fix this problem. I guess the ideal situation would be for a user to get a one-time use code from reception which allows them to use the computer for one hour. Once the time is up they'd have to get another code from us to use the computer again.

Does anyone know of some software (free or paid) that would work in this situation?

Comment: 1) I have seen this system in internet cafes, where you pay for an hour & get given a slip of paper with a password and will be logged off after an hour. 2) I also know, through looking a few years ago for personal use, that there is a lot of free internet cafe s/w out there. 3) I am behind my company's firewall, which is blocking my searches, so you will have to Google for yourself. HTH

Comment: Same question: http://superuser.com/questions/184302/how-can-i-limit-the-usage-time-for-an-user-profile-in-windows

Comment: The built-in parental controls only allow you to specify *time ranges* like Monday from 15:00 to 16:00, outside of which a user should not be able to log in. Are you sure that you are using the built-in controls and not some app that has a bug?

Comment: I don't think this is the same question as that. I don't have specific users that I can set up profiles for. Realistically, I could have completely different people using the computers each day.

As far as the built-in controls, I didn't set them up. It was like that before I was hired to fix the problem, and they told me they used the build in controls. For now Kiosk seems to be working ok.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with Antamedia Kiosk.

However, even though they say they support Windows XP (and I contacted them to ask specifically) not all the features work on XP. If you're looking for a product like this it does the trick, but beware the company (customer support has been of no help to me).